# javax.net.ssl.sslexception connection closed by peer

Tags: nativescript

I have just had to upgrade a Nativescript application to NS6 and now I'm getting the javax.net.ssl.sslexception connection closed by peer error on Android.

My web service is https and works fine with iOS. This is an enterprise app that will not go through the play store. Any thoughts please on a fix. Using http is not an option.

Updated app.js to this:-

```
var ad = require("tns-core-modules/utils/utils");
var context = ad.getApplicationContext();

androidApp.on(AndroidApplication.activityCreatedEvent, function (args: AndroidActivityBundleEventData) {

    // Needed updated Provider for corner cases with HTTP request using TSL on Android API19
    com.google.android.gms.security.ProviderInstaller.installIfNeededAsync(context, new com.google.android.gms.security.ProviderInstaller.ProviderInstallListener({
        onProviderInstalled:  () => {
            console.log("onProviderInstalled");
        },
        onProviderInstallFailed: (errorCode, intent) => {
            console.log("onProviderInstalledFailed");
            console.log("errorCode: " + errorCode);
        }
    }))
});

let application = require("tns-core-modules/application");




application.run({ moduleName: "app-root" });
```

Comment: Try this solution https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5157#issuecomment-352721710

Comment: Here is how I've implemented the solution in an Angular based application https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/app/main.ts#L30-L43

Comment: Add code to my OP. But getting the following error:- ERROR in ./app.js 51:4
Module parse failed: Identifier 'context' has already been declared (51:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| */
| var ad = require("tns-core-modules/utils/utils");
> var context = ad.getApplicationContext();
| 
| androidApp.on(AndroidApplication.activityCreatedEvent, function (args: AndroidActivityBundleEventData) {

Comment: You've missed a part of the code ... I guess the error is related to this line https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/app/main.ts#L22

Comment: All the code is there, var context = ad.getApplicationContext();
 I haven't declared context anywhere else.

Comment: Frank hard to say what's happening on your side - try creating a Playground https://play.nativescript.org/

Comment: Yes really odd, in the end for speed I have added a non https subdomain for the web services for Android, until I can get this fixed. I'll see if I can create a playground.

Comment: Also I had to recode the TS to JS as that is what I am using, quite possible I made a typo of didn't translate correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change "var context" to "var appcontext" or some other name and update code where "context" is used. Works for me.